# How to get the text from Listview to output to my external txt file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm new here and I'm new to programming in general.
I followed a YouTube video to make a simple todo list app for android and have since modified it into a visitors register.
I am copying people who sign in to an external txt file (that part is ok because I can grab the information as it's entered) but I have been struggling for about a week now to try to get the names of people who are signing out.

Basically a name and date/time get written to myExternalFile on btnAddTodo
is it possible in the btnDeleteDoneTodo to grab the names from deleteDoneTodos() and add them to myEternalFile??

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())

        rvTOdoItems.adapter = todoAdapter
        rvTOdoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val fileName = "log.txt"
        val filePath = "Sign In\\"
        val myExternalFile = File (getExternalFilesDir(filePath),fileName)

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString().uppercase()
            val regTitle = etRegTitle.text.toString().uppercase()
            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty() && regTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(todoTitle+"\n"+regTitle)
                myExternalFile.appendText(todoTitle +" "+ regTitle +" "+ todoAdapter.getCurrentDateTime() +"\n")
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
                etTodoTitle.text.clear()
                etRegTitle.text.clear()
            }
        }
        btnDeleteDoneTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
        }
    }
```

---

```
class Todo (
        val title : String,
        var isChecked: Boolean = false
```

---

```
    class TodoAdapter(
    val todos: MutableList<Todo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView:  View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    fun getCurrentDateTime() : Date {
        return Calendar.getInstance().time
    }

    fun addTodo (todo : Todo) {
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size-1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos () {
        todos.removeAll(Todo::isChecked)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

   private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvtodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
            tvtodoTitle.paintFlags = tvtodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            tvtodoTitle.paintFlags = tvtodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
            cdDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
            cdDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

I have tried appending just about every variable I think would be relevant with .toString() in the btnDeleteDoneTodos method, I have tried making separate lists in the deleteDoneTodos function, I tried making a new function that outputs a list but I have failed.
I don't know if it's even possible with the way it has all been implemented - like I said I'm very new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

edit.
I have managed to grab a single person leaving by adding the following leavers function to the todoAdapter class:

---

```
    fun leavers (tvtodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) : String {
    var going = ""
    if (isChecked) going = tvtodoTitle.text.toString()
    return going
}
```

---

which returns a single string (hence only one person) that I can then append to my external file. I have tried to change the function to mutable list  then iterate through it in btnDeleteDoneTodo listener but it will still only return one name.

I think I'm going to can this and go with Dewerros suggestion and try to setup a local Db, if anybody does have a solution it would still be gladly received as this has annoyed me for far too long now.

Comment: You want to get data from `RecyclerView` and put it into file by clicking `btnDeleteDoneTodo`?

Comment: Yes,. RecyclerView is showing the list generated by Todo method? - I want to send the title value to file if isChecked is true when btnDeleteDoneTodo is clicked

Comment: Yes, recycler view showing elements from list. You should get values from list and pass them into your file

Comment: It is not really good way to use `recyclerview` in this case. `RecyclerView` is presenter of information from file, database, server etc. And store data in .txt files also not really good way. I think `Room Database` is excellent choise in apps like this.